# how to alias a task in buildr

Tags: java, buildr

I might be doing something wrong, cuz I'm using buildr for not so long, so all comments are welcome.

My project structure is:

```
define :proj do
    define :web do
        task :run do
            # runs the web part of the project in a jetty
        end
    end
end
```

now if I want to start my project I have to type

```
buildr proj:web:run
```

I'd like to type simply

```
buildr run
```

instead. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the top level of your buildfile (i.e., outside of any `define`s), add

```
task :run => 'proj:web:run'
```

This defines a task named `run` whose sole prerequisite is the `proj:web:run` task.

Answer (score 3):

You can also make the task a 'local task',

```
Project.local_task 'run'
```

which means that whenever you are inside the `web` directory, typing `buildr run` will look for a locally-scoped that of that name.

Note that Buildr 1.4.3 added a standard `run` task so you typically wouldn't need to make `run` a local task; see http://buildr.apache.org/more_stuff.html#run for details.

Comment: NB that the `Project.local_task` invocation should be in the buildfile outside of the `define "project"...` block